# Make time changing DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html

When the form is SUBMITted, the working DIV named "second" will disappear after 5 seconds and the DIV named "three" will appear.
In addition, these processes will be one time and will not repeat itself.
Can you help me?

```html
<form name="kisi" method="post" action="gonder" id="kisi" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('second').style.display = '';">
  <input type="hidden" name="method" value="validateForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="serverValidationFields" name="serverValidationFields" value="">
  <div class="form-row">

    <div id="timerDiv" class="has-timer" style="">
      <span>Kalan Süre: </span> <span class="has-countdown__time" id="time"></span>
    </div><br><br>
    <input type="tel" class="f-input" name="kisilik" id="kisilik" pattern=".{0}|.{5,7}" autocomplete="off" maxlength="7" required oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" name="email" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);" onfocus="this.select();">
  </div>

  <button style="background:#076B79; color:white" class="btn" type="submit">ONAYLA</button>

</form>


<div id="second" class="2" style="display:none">
  <center><img class="smslogo" src="images/rolling.gif" /></center><br>
  <center>
    <p class="a">Lütfen Bekleyiniz. <br> Kisilik Doğrulaması Yapılıyor...</p>
  </center><br><br>
</div>

<div id="three" class="3" style="display:none">
  <center>
    <p class="a">THREE TEST DIV</p>
  </center><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: When you submit a form, the page is reloaded with the server's response. You need to use AJAX if you want to submit without reloading.

Comment: Lookup how to use setInterval and setTimeout. setTimeout is probably what you want. Just remember that you need to make the form not postback when you click submit. Lookup preventDefault() for this.

Comment: What is `InvalidMsg`?

Comment: The answer I gave below worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sms').submit(function(){
              setTimeout(function () { 
        $("#second").hide(); 
    }, 3000);   
               setTimeout(function () { 
        $("#three").show(); 
    }, 3000); 
    });
});
```

Comment: This might form the basis of an answer, but you've failed to explain why it's an answer, or what additional work might be required to implement it. As it stands it wont work with the OP's posted code.